# why does jQuery keyup fire duplicate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I want want the user to search by pressing the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key.

For some reason, when I search with the enter key more than once, my program starts making duplicate calls to the YouTube API, 2 sets of the same 5 videos. If you hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd> again, it now returns 3 sets of 5 videos... and so on.

Here's how I'm allowing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key:

```
//allow them start search by hitting enter key:
$("#youtube-headerContainer-searchBox").focus(function() {
    $(this).keyup(function(e) {
        if(e.which == 13) {
            startIndex=1;
            fetchVideos();
            console.log('enter key pressed');
        }
    });
});
```

I've made a fiddle so you can test it: http://jsfiddle.net/Vna3Z/1/
Simply type in a search, and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> again, and again. You'll see what I mean.

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you are attaching the same event handler, again and again.

Everytime the searchbox receives focus (so your `.focus()` handler runs), it means one more event handler, because `.keyup()` is used to attach an event handler on the element for the `keyup` event - everytime you call it, you attached one more!

I don't know why you need the `.focus()` handler, you could simply do

```
$("#youtube-headerContainer-searchBox").keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        startIndex=1;
        fetchVideos();
        console.log('enter key pressed');
    }
});
```

or read about [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/).

Comment: It was great watching this answer get bigger and bigger.  It helps fix the problem now.

Comment: @ntgCleaner The incremental answering style ;).

Comment: It's why you have 38.1k points ;) I was in the middle of writing the code for this answer, then it says "1 new answer, click here to refresh"

Comment: @ntgCleaner When I was new here, I saw some people doing this, and now I'm so used to it I would not be able to do it any other way :).

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix: Just use the `one` method to attach your focus event.

```
...

$("#youtube-headerContainer-searchBox").one('focus', function(){
    $(this).keyup(...);
});

...
```

jQuery docs: http://api.jquery.com/one

For your use case the `focus` handler is not needed, though. Input elements will receive the `keyup` event only when they are focused anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no need to have a 'focus' at all.  kapa's answer above gets rid of the focus and makes it just on keyup of that specific element.